# Mock IDynamoDBContext.ScanAsync method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, amazon-dynamodb, xunit

I'm trying to create unit tests for the next method:

```
     public async Task<Entity> GetEntityByIdAsync(Guid id)
     {
        List<ScanCondition> scanConditions = new List<ScanCondition>();

        scanConditions.Add(new ScanCondition("Date", ScanOperator.Between, GetDayRange(submitDate).Item1, GetDayRange(submitDate).Item2));
        scanConditions.Add(new ScanCondition("FieldId", ScanOperator.Equal, id));

        List<Entity> data = await _dynamoDbContext.ScanAsync<Entity>(scanConditions).GetRemainingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return data.OrderByDescending(r => r.SubmitDate).FirstOrDefault();  
    }
```

I created Mock for IDynamoDBContext, but I have problems with the setup of the ScanAsync method.

Had anybody any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What problems are you having?  Are there error messages?

Comment: Seth, I cannot setup ScanAsync method because it returns  AsyncSearch<T> class, and I cannot create an instance of this class because it doesn't have public constructor